# Why no `Action a -> Rules a` function

Tags: shake-build-system

In Shake there is a way to run an `Action` from `Rules`:

```hs
action :: Action a -> Rules ()
```

But I couldn't find a function which returns the result of the `Action`, namely:

```hs
actionWithResult :: Action a -> Rules a
```

How come?

Answer (score 1):

The reason is that `Rules` is run first, to completion, and then `Action`s are run - so it's somewhat staged programming. All `action` does is *records* an `Action`, to execute later.  The reason you have to run all the `Rules` first is so that it can collect all the possible types of rule that are available, since they're all available for all `Action`s.

Once you understand the staging, it's impossible to have `Action a -> Rules a`, because that implies running an `Action` and returning the result to `Rules`, so `Action` must run before `Rules` completes. However, `Actions a -> Rules ()` is fine, because it doesn't actually run then, but later.